# Stitching together Euclidean coordinate domains

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems

For a manifold, $\mathcal{M}$ and a countable cover of it by coordinate domains $U_1, \dots, U_n \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is there a way to "stitch" them together into a "common" Euclidean space with a common coordinate system?

It seems an intuitive enough "operation" but I am not at all sure of how to define a mechanism to do it. I was initially thinking of a map such as $F: U_1, \dots, U_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ but I have never seen a map defined like this. Alternatively, would a definition such as $F: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ suffice or are there more requirements that need to be fulfilled here?

Comment: Why don't standard Euclidean coordinates work in all of them?

Comment: I am assuming the $U_i$ are the domains of coordinate charts $\phi: V \supset \mathcal{M} \rightarrow U$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is a manifold, so I'm assuming separate coordinate systems.

Comment: Then you should make your question much more explicit.

Comment: I just did, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: countable or finite cover?

Comment: We are assuming countable.

Comment: Actually, because this is troubling me, I will edit the question to relax this assumption to something simpler, that is, a finite cover.